# Arraylist Search and Show object methods confusion

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

The two methods need to consider the boolean onLoan from the a second class named car for them to be able to be applied, what I mean is that only cars which onLoan == false should be considered. I got to the base of them tried what it came to my mind about getting this solved but nothing for me seems to work at the moment some suggestions? Thank you!

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class RentalCompany
 */
public void showAllCarsNotOnloan ()
{
    for ( Car car:cars) { 

    if (cars.size()>0 ) {

        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(car.getDescription());
        i++;

    }
    else if ( cars.size() < 0 ){
        System.out.println ("Add cars first");
    }
   }
}
```

and the second method

```
public Car searchCar(String description)
{
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.getDescription() == description) {
            return car; 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This car is not listed. Retry!!");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Note that in the first method you are inspecting the size of the cars list inside the loop iterating over the list. If you're inside the loop, the list cannot be empty.

Comment: String comparison needs `.equals` instead of `==`. `car.getDescription() == description`.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what's not working ?

Comment: Basically they both work well when invoking the methods, however when I rent a car invoking one of the methods in the arraylist for the objects car it changes a boolean onLoan to true, so what i want to try to do is in the case of the showallcar method is to invoke the method and then the method to print the (index + description of the car) but just the cars that are not onloan meaning onloan == false e.g    1: Red Ford, 3: Blue Jeep ( in this cases 0: and 2: would be missing because they are onLoan)

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the work:

The `Car` class:

```
public class Car {
    private boolean onLoan;
    // Other variables...

    public boolean isOnLoan() {
        return onLoan;
    }
    // Other methods....
}
```

Now, the `showAllCarsNotOnloan` method

```
public void showAllCarsNotOnloan() {
    if (cars.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Add cars first!");
        return;
    }

    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (!car.isOnLoan()) {
            System.out.println(car.getDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

and the `searchCar` method

```
public Car searchCar(String description) {
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.getDescription().equals(description)) {
            return car;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("This car not listed. Retry!!");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I had that in mind but it means I need to add a public method to the car class but the idea was to not change anything in the car class. It makes it a lot simpler adding the method but is there any other alternative? The search method also needs to look for just cars which onloan == false, so cars that are onLoan are not considered. Thank you very much for your comment and help!